# You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed

Tags: c#

Apologies if this has an obvious answer, I'm very new to coding and am just following along with a tutorial.

When I run this code, I get the following error message:
`You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor()`

I've looked around online but I am struggling to figure out what's wrong - it seems this error message appears when trying to use "new" in a MonoBehaviour, but I don't have "new" written into my code anywhere.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
public string CharacterName;
public RectTransform root;

public Character (string _name)
{
    CharacterManager cm = CharacterManager.instance;
    GameObject prefab = Resources.Load ("Characters/[" + _name + "]") as GameObject;
    GameObject ob = Instantiate(prefab, cm.characterPanel);

    root = ob.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
    CharacterName = _name;

    renderers.bodyRenderer = ob.transform.Find ("bodyLayer").GetComponent<Image> ();
    renderers.exprRenderer = ob.transform.Find ("exprLayer").GetComponent<Image> ();
}

class Renderers
{
    public Image bodyRenderer;
    public Image exprRenderer;
    
}

Renderers renderers;

}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Don't use a constructor but rather `Start()`

Answer (score 0):

We do not use constructors to initialize MonoBehaviours. They need to be initialized in the start or awake function, and use AddComponent/RemoveComponent to manage them at runtime, or just leave them on the prefab. You seem to be trying to create an object of class Character somewhere else, using this constructor. (Perhaps in another script?)